# How to match data entered in textfield with the columns of SQLite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating an SQLite based application. My database has a table named login and in login there are 3 columns id, username and password. I want that when a user logs in for the first time his username and password should be saved in the login table.

But when the same user opens the application next time he need not log in. His username and password should already be saved in database and from that it should be retrieved to open the application. How is this possible? How can I match the data entered in the textfield with the data present in the username and password of login table?

Comment: You should not save credentials in a database, use the keychain for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to second what Nick said, and that is to save username and password in the keychain. Here's a [link](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code) to a nice article with sample code on how to do that.

Secondly, I would like to go back to your question. AFAIK, text fields (or any input) aren't automatically bound to database fields. You have to do that yourself. What I mean is that you should write your select statements, and put the values in the fields as a part of those statements, then execute the statement you have just prepared.